# laravel sum of property in parent *and* children models?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Places that get appear in Timelines. These places can be grouped: a parent Place can have children Places (only one level deep).

Would like to lazy load the Places including visit counts of that Place *and* its children, and order by total count.
It's too many places to get 'em all up front and do the sum and sort afterwards.

Simplified example of the result I am trying to get:

```
- place B - visits 5, visits children 6, total visits 11
  - place B.1 - visits 2
  - place B.2 - visits 4
- place A - visits 5, visits children 0, total visits 5
- place C - visits 1, visits children 2, total visits 3
  - place C.1 - visits 2
```

With the code below I get all of that but the "total visits".

I am using straightforward relationships for the Place model:

```
public function children(){
  return $this->hasMany(Place::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function visits(){
  return $this->hasMany(Timeline::class);
}

public function visitsChildren(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Timeline::class, // the end result
        Place::class, // going through this one
        'parent_id', // foreign key on Place (child)
        'place_id', // foreign key on Timeline
        'id', // local key on Place (parent)
        'id' // local key on Place (child)
    );
}
```

I can get the visit count for that Place and the children and their visit counts.

```
\App\Models\Place::where(...)
  ->withCount('visits', 'visitsChildren')
  ->with('children', fn($q) => $q->withCount('visits'))
  ->orderByDesc('visits_count')
  ->get()
```

But how to add them up and sort by the total (without eager loading)?
I.e. can I "merge" `visits` and `visitsChildren`?

Tried this but that does not work because column `visits_count` and `visits_children_count` are (understandably) not available at that level:

```
...
->select(DB::raw('visits_count + visits_children_count as visits_including_children_count'))
->get()
```

**Update**: added the relationship for `visitsChildren` and the `DB::raw` attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` and `sum()` methods of [laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) and solve this

```
$result = \App\Models\Place::where(...)
    ->withCount('visits')
    ->with('children', fn($q) => $q->withCount('visits'))
    ->orderByDesc('visits_count')
    ->get();

$count = $result->map(function ($item) {
    $children_count = $item->children->sum(function ($child) {
        return $child->visits_count ?? 0;
    });
    return $children_count + $item->visits_count;
});
dd($count);
```

Comment: This does the work *after* getting the Places. I need the info *before* getting them.